# SQL Server, excluding many rows with NOT IN aside from a few rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

Is there a clean way to add to this subquery to not remove seven specific rows

```
AND sa.AccountID NOT IN (
                          SELECT AccountID
                          FROM
                          SubAccountData
                          WHERE AccountDataTypeID = 10315
                                AND 
                                Data IN (
                                          SELECT KeyData
                                          FROM AccountDataValues
                                          WHERE AccountDataTypeID = 10315
                                                AND 
                                                ValueData LIKE 'FS001%MPLS'
                                         )
                         )
```

This pulls roughly 1000 rows and there are 7 I do not want to pull. I have the sa.AccountID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a `NOT IN` you just need to exclude the rows from being returned from the subquery:

```
... NOT IN (SELECT AccountID
            FROM SubAccountData
            WHERE AccountID NOT IN (the 7 IDs)
            AND AccountDateTypeID = 10315
            AND Data IN (...)
           )
```